# How bind CWebUser with model User

Tags: php, authentication, yii, yii-components

How to bind **Yii:app()->user** to the model **User**. That there was a connection type: **Yii::app()->user->getUser()**

For example, I want to get the currently logged in user's email:

**Yii::app()->user->getUser()->email;**

I readed wiki post:http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/80/add-information-to-yii-app-user-by-extending-cwebuser-better-version/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyWbuser.php in components:

```
class MyWebUser extends CWebUser{

    private $_profile = null;
    public $loginUrl='/';

    public function init(){
       parent::init();
       if(!$this->getIsGuest()){
            $this->_profile = User::model()->findByPk($this->getId());
       }
    }
    public function getProfile(){
       return $this->_profile;
   }
}
```

In config.php:

```
    'user' => array(
        'class' => 'MyWebUser',
    )
```

Then you can use:

```
Yii::app()->user->profile->name
```

Comment: This a good idea) As I understand it instead of UserIdentity?

Comment: Yes it extends the CWebUser

Answer (score 1):

Try this add this code to your useridentity authenticate function

```
$this->setState('email',$this->email);
```

And use to access that email anywhere as shown

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('email');
```

Comment: This is good idea. Thank you, Ninad) By the way, with yesterday's task I coped =) @Ninad

Comment: Good Cheers :) What was the issue ??

Comment: I'am used model User instead of RegisterForm )